# Python Tk display and edit a file

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I'm trying to write a Python GUI program in Tkinter. I have the basic template, but I need it to open a file when you hit `File > Open`.

How could I add this function? Menu bars and labels are already there.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ScrolledText import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S, Menu
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Grades")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Grades:")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Average\n Grade:")
        lbl.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=5)

        textPad = ScrolledText(self)
        textPad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Save",command=save_command )
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Close")
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Help", command=about_command)
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK")
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)        

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)       

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="Student")
        submenu.add_command(label="New Student")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Import', menu=submenu, underline=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=open_command)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)        


    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

def about_command():
    label = tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "Grade keeping\n program by Starwarsfan2099")

def save_command(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    if file != None:
    # slice off the last character from get, as an extra return is added
        data = self.textPad.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

def open_command():
        file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='rb',title='Select a file')
        if file != None:
            contents = file.read()
            textPad.insert('1.0',contents)
            file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textPad` is a local variable to the `initUI` method, and therefore after the method has terminated, that reference to the object will be lost. In other words, you cannot access `textPad` from outside the `initUI` function.

In your `initUI` method, change the following two lines:

```
textPad = ScrolledText(self)
textPad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
```

to (making `textPad` a field of the class `Example`):

```
self.textPad = ScrolledText(self)
self.textPad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
```

I have changed other things of your code in order to improve it. Specifically, I have made those global functions methods of the class `Example`, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from ScrolledText import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S, Menu
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Grades")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Grades:")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Average\n Grade:")
        lbl.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=5)

        self.textPad = ScrolledText(self)
        self.textPad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Save",command=self.save_command)
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.onExit)
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        hbtn = Button(self, text="Help", command=self.about_command)
        hbtn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK")
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)        

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)       

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="Student")
        submenu.add_command(label="New Student")

        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Import', menu=submenu, underline=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=self.open_command)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)        

    def onExit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

    def about_command(self):
        label = tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "Grade keeping\n program by Starwarsfan2099")

    def save_command(self):
        file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
        if file != None:
        # slice off the last character from get, as an extra return is added
            data = self.textPad.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
            file.write(data)
            file.close()

    def open_command(self):
            file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='rb',title='Select a file')
            if file != None:
                contents = file.read()
                self.textPad.insert('1.0', contents)
                file.close()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Anyway, I encourage you to look up the changes, so that you understand what you were doing not so well. To be honest, I have not watched it completely, but the changes I have made are IMO an improvement.